# Is Khalid ibn al-Walid a celebrated figure in Islam?

Tags: war, people

**Khalid**

Apparently there was an Islamic general called Khalid ibn al-Walid.

[Britannica encyclopedia](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Khalid-ibn-al-Walid)

> Khālid ibn al-Walīd, byname Sīf, or Sayf, Allāh (Arabic: “Sword of God”), (died 642)

**Hero**

Apparently Khalid conquered Mecca alongside Muhammad, and then conquered the Arabian peninsula and Iraq, before routing the Byzantine empire in Syria and Palestine.

Khalid is regarded as having secured the spread of Islam in a number of provinces.

[Britannica encyclopedia](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Khalid-ibn-al-Walid)

> Khālid was later converted (627/629) and joined Muhammad in the conquest of Mecca in 629; thereafter he commanded a number of conquests and missions in the Arabian Peninsula. After the death of Muhammad, Khālid recaptured a number of provinces that were breaking away from Islam. He was sent northeastward by the caliph Abū Bakr to invade Iraq, where he conquered Al-Ḥīrah. Crossing the desert, he aided in the conquest of Syria; and, though the new caliph, ʿUmar, formally relieved him of high command (for unknown reasons), Khālid remained the effective leader of the forces facing the Byzantine armies in Syria and Palestine. Routing the Byzantine armies, he surrounded Damascus, which surrendered on Sept.

**Question**

Is Khalid a celebrated figure in Islam?

Comment: "Allah" is God. "Sayf Allah" means 'Sword of God'. Khalid bin Waleed was called the later. He is a celebrated figure in Sunni Islam.

Comment: @UmH Ok, I have removed the term Allah. I must have read the Britannica article wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Khalid bin Waleed was a Sahabi, i.e. a companion of the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ and he is well known in Islam as being an accomplished fighter and military commander. The Prophet ﷺ  said regarding him:

> نعم عبد الله وأخو العشيرة خالد بن الوليد وسيف من سيوف الله سله الله عز وجل على الكفار والمنافقين
>
> What a good slave of Allah and a brother of the tribe Khalid bin al-Waleed is, he is a sword from the swords of Allah that He has unsheathed against disbelievers and hypocrites.
>
> <sup>— [Musnad Ahmad](https://sunnah.com/ahmad:43) ,  [Jami at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:3846) - corroborated in [Saheeh Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3757)</sup>